# Cairo not found on Windows in GitHub Action

Tags: python, windows, github-actions, gtk3, cairo

I'm trying to run my Python test suite in a GitHub Action on Ubuntu, macOS, and Windows, and the Windows version fails when I import the `cairosvg` library.

```
tests\test_svg_turtle.py:6: in <module>
    from cairosvg import svg2png
.tox\py\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py:26: in <module>
    from . import surface  # noqa isort:skip
.tox\py\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py:9: in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
.tox\py\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py:48: in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
.tox\py\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py:45: in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
E   OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
E   no library called "cairo" was found
E   no library called "libcairo-2" was found
E   cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
E   cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
E   cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

The [`cairosvg` documentation](https://cairosvg.org/documentation/) says that you need to install C++ and cairo. It suggests following the [WeasyPrint documentation](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/latest/first_steps.html) for more details. That says you need to install [GTK3](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases).

I haven't used Windows much with GitHub actions, so how do you install GTK3? Is that even what `cairosvg` needs?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed `cairo` with the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cairo
```

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP, and when I try to run the above command, the pip command failed. Note that may caused by the reason that I don't have visual studio C++ compiler installed.